# React onClick not firing on first click, second click is fine

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using Two Component like **FirstComponent** and **SecondComponent**. SecondComponent is rendering on FirstComponent. I send **hanldeClick()** function  from FirstComponent to SecondComponent. **But hanldeClick() function not response on the first click**.

My code:

```
//First Component 
export function FirstComponent(props) {
  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log('please response');
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <SecondComponent handleClick ={handleClick } />
    </div>
  );
}

//Second Component
export function SecondComponent(props) {
  const { handleClick } = props;

  return (
    <div>
      <Table>
        <TableBody>
          {mayArray.map(file => (
            <TableRow key={Math.random()}>
......................
              <TableCell>
                <Button
                  onClick={() => {
                    hanldeClick();
                  }}>
                  Cros
                </Button>
              </TableCell>
..........................
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You're passing `hanldeClick` to `SecondComponent` but accessing `handleClick` from props. It's a typo.

Comment: Sorry! I couldn't understand about your solution. Please explain if possible.

Comment: Spelling mismatch. `hanldeClick is not equal to handleClick`

Comment: Sorry Bro, You are right. That's here problems. But my code was right on the two component(same name without spelling mistake).

Comment: Remove the `Math.random()` for key generation. Remove the `key` altogether once and try it again.

Comment: I have added this as an answer with more details and link to docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From React official [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html) :-

> Keys should be stable, predictable, and unique. Unstable keys (like
> those produced by Math.random()) will cause many component instances
> and DOM nodes to be unnecessarily recreated, which can cause
> performance degradation and lost state in child components.

You have used `Math.random()` for keys and I think that's the cause of the weird behavior you might be getting. Remove that and use a more reliable one like a **unique id**.

Comment: Great! You save my huge time